# Q-Learning Reward function racing game

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have written a deep Q-learning algorithm with [this](http://neuro.cs.ut.ee/demystifying-deep-reinforcement-learning/) website (without terminal state) for a car racing game where you get reset when get of the track. I got input of speed, some distance sensors and the progress of the track in percent. Output is the acceleration of the car and the steering angle.

My question is how should is set the reward and the function to get target Q-Value.

The neural net accepts values in range $(0,1]$ as input and target, so my idea was to set the reward to `progressInPercent/2 + 0.5` (or + 0.01) when the car was reset.

My problem is since the neural net (Q-Function) can only take $(0,1]$ as target, how do I make sure these values don't grow over 1?
Using `tt = rr + γmaxa’Q(ss’, aa’)` as training target doesn't work.

Or should I take something else as reward?

Comment: fyi -- You can use math typesetting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

What about clipping the reward, after scaling it? By clipping around (0,1] all outliers are projected back to the extreme values.

Answer (score 0):

"My question is how should is set the reward and the function to get target Q-Value."

I think you can only set the reward manually and not the function. Scaling rewards to between 0 and 1, is indeed generally done in RL algorithms. One way to go about it is, deduce what could be your maximum reward per step and then divide your obtained reward with it.